# Trying to verify a value from a large responsive Web table

Tags: angularjs, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to verify a value from a specific column in a huge web table. But none of the locator is unique and selenium cant find all the element.
using selenium and cucumber jvm.

below is one of the html code for a cell value:

```
<div id="1504183962844-0-uiGrid-03UI-cell" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-03UI" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" tabindex="-1">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">ncautoemail_dtyhe@gmail.com</div>
```

it has around 80 cell in the row and id keep changing. any advice on locating element and verify the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
//div[@id='1504183962844-0-uiGrid-03UI-cell' and @class='ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-03UI' and @role='gridcell']
```

And

```
//div[class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope']/preceding-sibling::div[@@id='1504183962844-0-uiGrid-03UI-cell']
```

Or

```
(//div[@id='1504183962844-0-uiGrid-03UI-cell' and @class='ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-03UI' and @role='gridcell'])[14]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your ans. But the id always change so 2nd time it cudnt find with the same path.

Comment: You can remove id from my path .. I have put other parameters ... May they will help you.. I have compined them with and operator

Comment: there are still another 40 column with the same parameter (class,role). And if I put it in List of element and iterate thru it found only 12 element, the rest is not visible in the table untill I scroll to the right. And javascript scroll to the element also doesnt work cause it doesn find a specific element.

Comment: What is the position of your required element? Can you specify the position and check if the next time the position is not change then I can help you on same

Comment: If you know the position I have added a sample xpath which will select your element on 14th position .. change as per your required element .. array in xpath is started from 1 so don't use -1 logic here

Comment: Yeah the position doesnt change. It stays in the same place always. and I cant scroll to that bcz that responsive table is in separate div. I tried clicking any of the element on that div and tried to scroll to the right but didnt work.

Comment: Can you upload your html page source to any place and provide a link to me .. I will generate a xpath for you

Comment: yeah that sample xpath works for first matching 12 element. but for the 24th element it doesnt find it cause of the scrolling.

Comment: Then scroll you page by providing focus